# Assistance needed with vbs to change Admin Account

Tags: authentication, vbscript, admin

I've been tasked with creating a vbs to do the following: 
If NewAdmin exists then Set password for NewAdmin and disable Local Administrator account 
Else Rename local Administrator account to NewAdmin and set password.

Thanks again for the quick reply.  I have changed the code below accordingly and am now trying to use the Windows Script Encoder to obfuscate the password.  I understand that there is still a risk involved as this could be decoded, but the script will not be stored on the user's computer and as such will not pose much of a threat.

The code now shows the three added lines needed for the Windows Script Encoder to do it's job, but I can't get it to work.  I run the following command from the command line:

screnc /l vbscript admin_script.vbs admin_script.vbe

It creates the admin_script.vbe successfully.  But then when I attempt to run the encoded script it presents the following error message:

```
Script:    C:\...\admin_script.vbe
Line:      2
Char:      1
Error:     Expected Statement
Code:      800A0400
Source:    Microsoft VBscript compilation error
```

The unencoded script runs without issues.  I have tried another method to encode the data using a vbscript I located online, but it does the same thing ... obfuscates the data but the script doesn't work afterwords.  I also read that it may be an encoding issue and that I needed to save the vbs as UTF-8 without BOM but that didn't work either.

If anyone knows how to get this Windows Script Encoder working I would greatly appreciate it.  Also, if there is another method for encrypting / obfuscating the code, any suggestions are welcome.  I will say that I'm not a big fan of creating an executable from VBS, but will resort to that if necessary.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
'**Start Encode**
OPTION EXPLICIT
DIM objNetwork, objUser, objComputer
DIM strPassword, strAdminUserName, strNewAdminUserName, strComputer, strUser

' Get Computer Name and make it all uppercase
SET objNetwork = CREATEOBJECT("Wscript.Network")
strComputer = UCASE(objNetwork.ComputerName)
' Setting veriable for IF statement
strUser= "NewAdmin"
' The old name of the administrator user account (normally administrator)
strAdminUserName = "Administrator"
' The new name of the administrator user account
strNewAdminUserName = "NewAdmin"
' New Password for administrator account.
strPassword = "passwordhere"

On Error Resume Next
Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/" & strUser & ",user")
If (Err.Number = 0) Then
  On Error GoTo 0
    ' Set password of admin user account
    setPWD strComputer,strNewAdminUserName,strPassword
    ' Disable Local Administrator account
    Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/Administrator, user")
    objUser.AccountDisabled = True
    objUser.SetInfo  
Else
  On Error GoTo 0
    ' Rename admin user account
    renameUser strComputer,strAdminUserName,strNewAdminUserName
    ' Set password of admin user account
    setPWD strComputer,strNewAdminUserName,strPassword  
End If

' enter code hereReset password for a local user account on a given computer
SUB setPWD(strComputer,strUser,strPassword)

    DIM objUser
    ' Ignore error if user account isn't found or error changing password
    ON ERROR RESUME NEXT 
    SET objUser = GETOBJECT("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/" & strUser & ",user")
    IF err.number = 0 THEN
        objUser.SetPassword strPassword
        objUser.SetInfo
    END IF
    ON ERROR GOTO 0

END SUB

' Rename a local user account on a given computer
SUB renameUser(strComputer,strFromName, strToName)

    DIM objComputer,objUser
    ' Ignore error if user account isn't found or error moving user
    ON ERROR RESUME NEXT
    SET objComputer = GETOBJECT("WinNT://" & strComputer)
    SET objUser = GETOBJECT("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/" & strFromName & ",user")
    IF err.number = 0 THEN
        objComputer.MoveHere objUser.ADsPath,strToName
    END IF
    ON ERROR GOTO 0

END SUB
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` and check what error you get. Also, [WMI](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/05/17/how-can-i-rename-a-local-user-account-on-a-windows-xp-computer.aspx) might be an easier way to do what you want. The best solution from a systems management PoV, however, would be a group policy.

Comment: I saw the suggestion to use group policy preferences quite a bit while researching and wish we could utilize GPP, but our server team has A LOT on their plate and am not sure they would have time / or would be willing to complete the work.

Comment: They should. Group policies make their lives easier, giving them better/centralized control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
```

to this

```
If (Err.Number = 0) Then
```

Comment: WOW!  Simple change, but it looks to have possibly done the job.  I will do further testing when time permits, but thank you very much for the response.